# How i can get list date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I using this code for get list `AND PD.DT IN (ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 1), ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 2), ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 3))` 
but it not automatic if i can get 5 month i must add `ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 4),ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 5)`
how can i make an automatic list ?

```
PRERESULT AS (
    SELECT
        PD.PAYABLEDATE,
        AMOUNT,
        TCOUNT,
        MAX(PD.PAYABLEDATE) OVER(
            PARTITION BY 'Contract'
        ) AS MPD
    FROM
        PD
        INNER JOIN TAKSIT T ON PD.DT BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 1) AND ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, TCOUNT) 
                              AND PD.DT IN (ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 1), ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 2), ADD_MONTHS(T.TDATE, 3)) 
                              -- AND TO_CHAR(PD.DT, 'DD') = TO_CHAR(T.TDATE, 'DD')
```

Tcount = is number month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it a query:

```
x IN (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(y, LEVEL) 
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
)
```

This query produces a list of 5 rows with a single column of a number 1 to 5:

```
SELECT LEVEL
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```

We just use the number in the add months call. The 5 can be variable too and come from another column in the query:

```
x IN (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(y, LEVEL) 
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= z
)
```

Comment: `IN (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(T.TDate, LEVEL) 
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Tcount
)` this code correct